# Passwords don't get stored properly in SQL Server from C# aplication

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm having an issue where my hashed passwords are not getting properly stored in SQL Server. The fields for password and salt (saved in base64) are `nvarchar(128)` and I'm using this function to encode the string (credits to user blowdart for it):

```
private static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(byte[] plainText, byte[] salt) {
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

    byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes =
      new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++) {
        plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainText[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++) {
        plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];
    }

    return algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
}
```

I'm creating the byte array using the following method:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)
```

And I'm saving it to the database with this method:

```
public Boolean CredentialNew(AuthBE authBE) {
    con.ConnectionString = conection.GetCon();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "PERSONA.CredentialNew";

    string HashedPasswordString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(authBE.HashedPassword);

    try {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", HashedPasswordString);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salt", authBE.Salt);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    } catch (SqlException x) {
        throw new Exception(x.Message);
    } finally {              
            con.Close();

    }
    return success;
}
```

After that, this is what appears in my database. The characters appear with squares and often times many?

[image]

Comment: The `n` in `nvarchar` stands for Unicod, or UTF-16. It's weird how the driver doesn't properly convert it, try manually converting your UTF-8 hashed password string to UTF-16 using the [`Encoding.Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.convert?view=netcore-3.1) method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `authBE.HashedPassword` looks like raw byte code, not encoded string. So you should use something else than `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(authBE.HashedPassword)`, f. ex. `Convert.ToBase64String(authBE.HashedPassword)`.

Comment: You can also change column type in database to [binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/binary-and-varbinary-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) type. There you not have to change it to string at all.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a solution, but I have a little problem I think? When I just ```Convert.ToString()``` the password field says ```System.byte[]```. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, because if Convert not have implemented special conversion for type, uses `.ToString()` method, and if it is not overloaded, for objects returns name of used type.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still have not tested if it works 100% but at least I see the data entered properly in the database.